# rubber gem AMI error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the rubber.yml config file. If I set the:

```
cloud_providers:
  aws:
    region: eu-west-1
```

The cap rubber:create_staging will fail, AMI ID '' does not exists. Why? And how to get around it?

If I set it to:

```
cloud_providers:
  aws:
    region: us-east-1
```

Things works just fine.

Comment: Are you able to create an instance with this AMI ID in eu-west-1 through the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, diden't realise I needed a different AMI in different regions.

Once I found the right one, it worked. AMIs can be fount at amazon of course but also at [alestic](http://alestic.com/)